# Filter in Spring with Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter

I'm in a Spring project, and I need of filters.
Now I have already read about "Interceptor Vs Filter" and for now I choose filter.

So I have this class as filter

```
public class LogFilter implements Filter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain   chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        this.log.info("IP " + ipAddress + ", Time " + new Date().toString());

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

        // Get init parameter
        String testParam = config.getInitParameter("test-param");
        this.log.info("Test Param:" + testParam);
    }

    public void destroy() {

    // Add code to release any resource
    }
}
```

And this method for registration of filter's bean in java config ( no xml configuration )

```
  @Bean
  public LogFilter filter() {

    LogFilter filter = new LogFilter();
    this.beanFactory.autowireBean(filter);
    return filter;
  }
```

Now this filter works for every url of my app, how can I choose which url should be "under filter" ?

**EDIT**
I solved this in this way

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean regFilter() {

    FilterRegistrationBean regFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    regFilter.setFilter(new LogFilter());
    regFilter.addUrlPatterns("/test");
    return regFilter;
}
```

Thanks to the hint in comment, I found [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean)

Comment: I think it requires a `FilterRegistrationBean`; I may be mistaken though.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using annotation to configure your web @WebFilter to annotate your Filter as per http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html.

Note that those annotation should be put in the LogFilter itself. And that it has no relation to spring bean or spring context. Those configuration are scanned and processed by the application server, e.g Tomcat, but Spring.